# How to get the index of an numpy.ndarray

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I would to print the images on index `i` but I get an error of `only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`. How can I convert `I` to int for each iteration

I have tried replacing `images[i]` with `images[n]` it worked but not the result I want.

```
c = [1 1 1 0 1 2 2 3 4 1 3]
#c here is list of cluster labels obtained after Affinity propagation 
num_clusters = len(set(c))
images = os.listdir(DIR_NAME)

for n in range(num_clusters):
   print("\n --- Images from cluster #%d ---" % n)
   for i in np.argwhere(c == n):
     if i != -1:
        print("Image %s" % images[i])
```

I expect the output to be the name of the image, but I instead get `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index` that is because `i` is of type `numpy.ndarray`

Comment: Have you looked at the output of `argwhere`, at `i`?  What's the purpose of the -1 test?

Comment: yes I did is type of  `numpy.ndarray`

Comment: `argwhere` doesn't produce `-1` (like some string or list 'find' methods).  The array will have 0 rows if it doesn't find a match.  I'd suggest printing `c==n`, `np.where(c==n)` and `np.argwhere(c==n)` to get a better sense of what that code does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [doc of `np.argwhere`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html), it does not return a list of integers, but a list of lists

```py
x = array([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]])
np.argwhere(x>1)
>>> array([[0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2]])

y = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7])
np.argwhere(y>3)
>>> array([[4], [5], [6]])
```

so without knowing what your `c` looks like, I assume your `i` will be of the form `np.array([[3]])` instead of an integer, and therefore your code fails. Print `i` for testing and extract (e.g. `i[0][0]` and a test that it is non-empty) the desired index first before you do `i != -1`.

#### Meta

It is best practise to post a minimal reconstructable example, i.e. other people should be able to copy-paste the code and run it. Moreover, if you post at least a couple lines of the traceback (instead of just the error), we would be able to tell where exactly the error is happening.

Comment: technically argwhere produces a 2d array

Comment: @Snowbunting thanks, `c` is a list as in `c = [1 1 1 0 1 2 2 3 4 1 3]` printing `I` gives me `[3]` of type `numpy.ndarray`

Comment: `np.argwhere` on my list returns a list of one element I therefore accessed by `i[0]` at thanks again @Snowbunting :)